# Hive function quarter() returns 'invalid function'

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

This says the function quarter() was introduced in Hive 1.3

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

I am using the default version of HDInsight (3.1) to run Hadoop:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-component-versioning/

When I try to use the quarter function I get:

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/C:/apps/dist/hive-0.13.0.2.1.15.1-0001/conf/hive-log4j.properties
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apps/dist/hadoop-2.4.0.2.1.15.1-0001/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apps/dist/hbase-0.98.0.2.1.15.1-0001-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 10:1 Invalid function 'quarter'

What am I missing?

Comment: the work around for me was to use a case statement to get the quarter: case month(gmtdatetime) 
When 1 then 1
When 2 then 1
When 3 then 1
When 4 then 2
When 5 then 2
When 6 then 2
When 7 then 3
When 8 then 3
When 9 then 3
Else 4 end as QuarterOf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately HDInsight 3.1 is only running Hive 0.13.1 and the quarter function isn't available until version 1.3.  You can see all of the hive release [here](https://github.com/apache/hive/releases?after=release-1.1.0-rc2)

Comment: Is there a work around so I can group and sum using quarter() ?

Comment: You could just add the version 1.3 Hive jar to the cluster during creation and then reference the quarter UDF as a temporary function.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/01/14/how-to-add-custom-hive-udfs-to-hdinsight.aspx

Comment: The same is valid for the FIRST() function

Answer (score 2):

If you're on an older version of hive that doesn't support quarter(), try this:

```
ceil(month(date) / 3.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Hive versions in various releases of HDInsight are given below. As per this, your hive version is 0.13.1 and the quarter is supported in hive version 1.3.

HDINSIGHT VERSION 3.2-  Hive-0.14.0

HDINSIGHT VERSION 3.1-  Hive-0.13.1

HDINSIGHT VERSION 3.0-  Hive-0.12.0

HDINSIGHT VERSION 2.1-  Hive-0.11.0