# Hive DateTime Truncators (QUARTER, WEEK, DAYOFWEEK)?

Tags: sql, datetime, hive, hiveql

Is there any expressions to get `QUARTER`, `WEEK` and `DAYOFWEEK` of a DateTime field in Hive (v0.14.1) which do the same thing as these buildin functions in MySql?

here is the specification of what I want (from MySql doc):

[QUARTER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter)
[WEEK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)
[DAYOFWEEK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)

NOTE:
1. the function quarter() was introduced in Hive 1.3, but I need a expr to support lower version.
2. the function weekofyear() is supported instead of week(), but there is a little difference. but it's okay, so just ignore this one.

Comment: Did you check the Hive documentation?  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688532/hive-function-quarter-returns-invalid-function

Comment: since I'm using Hive 0.14.1, the quarter() function is not available. and do you have any idea about how to implement the dayofweek() function via expr ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose the DateTime field is `order_time`

- DAYOFWEEK: `PMOD(DATEDIFF(order_time, '2012-01-01'), 7)`
- WEEK: `WEEKOFYEAR(order_time)`
- QUARTER (hive <1.3): `(INT((MONTH(order_time)-1)/3)+1)`
- QUARTER (hive >=1.3): `QUARTER(order_time)`

Answer (score 1):

It always helps to know how to turn a month into a quarter using just math:

```
floor((cast(substr(visit_date, 6,2) as int) - 1) / 3) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To get QUARTER for Hive < 1.3.0 use `ceil(month(order_time) / 3.0)` and `quarter(order_time)` for Hive >= 1.3.0

For dayofweek use `date_format('2016-12-01' ,'u')`

and `WEEKOFYEAR(order_time)` for week number in a year

Answer (score 0):

At https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF, you can find 'Date Functions'. You'll find 'Quarter' and 'Week' there.

For dayofweek, you could use something like:

```
CASE 
    WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2012-10-12 20:53:12"), 'EEEE') = 'Monday' THEN 1 
    WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2012-10-12 20:53:12"), 'EEEE') = 'Tuesday' THEN 2
    WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2012-10-12 20:53:12"), 'EEEE') = 'Wednesday' THEN 3 
    WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2012-10-12 20:53:12"), 'EEEE') = 'Thursday' THEN 4 
    WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2012-10-12 20:53:12"), 'EEEE') = 'Friday' THEN 5
    WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2012-10-12 20:53:12"), 'EEEE') = 'Saturday' THEN 6 
    WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp("2012-10-12 20:53:12"), 'EEEE') = 'Sunday' THEN 7  
  END AS day_of_week
```